# When starting React Native app, I'm error that functions are not valid as React child

Tags: reactjs, react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

I'm trying to start my App with react-native-navigation and persistStore from redux persistStore.
I'm getting warning that functions are not valid as React child.This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render.

Is there any workaround to start this initial screen, recently I've added startApp function and call it inside render.

Here is my initial component for starting app:

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
 import { Provider } from "react-redux";
 import { View, Text } from "react-native";
 import { persistStore } from "redux-persist";
 import { Navigation } from "react-native-navigation";
 import Mapbox from "@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl";

 import { registerScreens } from "./screens";
 import store from "./store/configureStore";
 import { appInit, getInitialScreen } from "./appInit";
 import { handleErrorObject } from "./lib/handleError";

 Mapbox.setAccessToken("pk.eyJ123425KKbcgNww");

 export default class App extends Component {
  startApp = () => {
    const persistor = persistStore(store, null, () => {
        registerScreens(store, Provider);

        appInit(store)
            .then(() => {
                const initialScreen = getInitialScreen(store.getState());

                Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
                    screen: {
                        screen: initialScreen
                    },
                    passProps: {
                        persistor
                    },
                    drawer: {
                        left: {
                            screen: "DrawerMenuScreen"
                        }
                    },
                    appStyle: {
                        orientation: "portrait"
                    }
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                handleErrorObject("Error initializing app", error);
            });
    });
};
render() {
    return <View>{this.startApp}</View>;
}
}
```

Comment: I suggest you use this React Navigation library https://reactnavigation.org/ with this can make initial screen more easier

Answer (score 0):

There are two things wrong with your code.

**startApp** is a function and in order to render the **JSX** returned from any function you need to call it as `{this.startApp()}`

You do not have any **JSX** to be returned inside `startApp`, since it is just setting the values to the `persistStore` and would contain a [persistor](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) object.

I suggest you should take a look at the [docs](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/v2/#/docs/Installing?id=you-can-use-react-native-navigation-o) and this [article](https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-navigation-v2-by-wix-getting-started-7d647e944132) to know more about the usage of `react-native-navigation`